# Android Change background color when clicked

Tags: android, android-button

I'm trying to change the background color of a `Button` when it is clicked, I can change the background color when I have the `Button` pressed down when I release the `Button` the button returns to its default color. I'm not sure where to go from here I have been trying to find a solution to this problem.

`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.game.dice.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/but1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 1"
        android:background="@drawable/button_color"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/but2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 2"
        android:background="@drawable/button_color"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@color/button_pressed"/>
<item android:state_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@color/button_focused"/> 
<item android:drawable="@color/button_default"/> 
</selector>
```

Comment: Does it have to be through XML? Otherwise you can do it with the buttons OnClickListener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because by default when the button is touched it will take click instead of focus.If you want button to be focused and change its color when pressed add this to your button in xml.

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick setup in Java on how to do it;

```
private Button mButton;
mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but1);

mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
    });
```

You basically make a ClickListener than reacts whenever the button is clicked. From here we change the buttons background color to Black. If you want it to change with each click, you can apply more logic.

Comment: I like the idea of trying to use Java,

Comment: I like the idea of trying to using Java,  I'm new to android and I'm sure I'm missing something here but I'm not sure what, does the onClick look like this **onClick="mButton";**. Should I edit the code in the question to reflect my updated code or is that considered bad form here?

Comment: The code I gave you is everything you need, the text below is just a description of the code. I think it's easiest if you throw in an **EDIT:** at the bottom of your post and put your new code there.

Answer (score 1):

The correct xml is :

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true"
android:drawable="@color/button_pressed"/>
<item android:state_focused="false"
android:drawable="@color/button_focused"/> 
<item android:drawable="@color/button_default"/> 
</selector>`
```

you can't focused all true.

Answer (score 0):

In your drawable, the last `<item>` indicates the default state. Change that.

Edit:

I'm sorry i undestood wrong. You have to do this in Java or Kotlin whichever you are using. This is more business logic than it is "view".

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:color="@color/button_pressed" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/button_pressed" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/button_default" />
<item android:color="@color/button_pressed" />
```

Answer (score 0):

## Try this one

---

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!-- Non focused states -->
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/on_the_go"
    android:color="@color/colorText" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/on_the_go_selected"
    android:color="@color/colorSkyBlue"/>

<!-- Focused states -->
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/on_the_go"
    android:color="@color/colorText"/>
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/on_the_go_selected"
    android:color="@color/colorSkyBlue"/>

<!-- Pressed -->
<item android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/on_the_go"
    android:color="@color/colorText"/>
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/on_the_go_selected"
    android:color="@color/colorSkyBlue" />

</selector>
```

---

## Happy to help you

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this ?

```
myButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

This code is in your onClick method.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                button.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(),R.color.colorBlack));
            }
        });
```

> **NOTE** if you wan't to reset a button's background color to default than use below code

```
button.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);
```